# How to use expo-clipboard events to automatically paste an URL?

Tags: react-native, expo

In my react native expo mobile app I want to run a specific function when the user has an url copied in their clipboard. For this I subscribed to expo clipboard event. But I don't see anything in my console.

```
useEffect(() => {

   const subscription = Clipboard.addClipboardListener((ClipboardEvent) => {
        if (ClipboardEvent.contentTypes.includes(Clipboard.ContentType.URL)) {
          Clipboard.getStringAsync().then(content => {
            console.log(content)
          });
        }  
      });
      
    return () => {
        Clipboard.removeClipboardListener(subscription)
        };
    
 }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  Call this function in useEffect and save it using state

```
  const fetchCopiedText = async () => {
const text = await Clipboard.getStringAsync();
setCopiedText(text);
```

};

hope so it will works for you

Comment: Thanks. But I want to do it when the items in the clipboard change (for an example when the user copied a new URL) that's why I used clipboard listener to listen to the event but it's not working.

Comment: it is not working for both android and ios or just one? because  ios some versions are not supporting it

Comment: It's not working for android. I couldn't test the iOS because I don't have a mac to test the development build.

Comment: then try once to change the version .